# Transition-group not working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

https://codepen.io/joshuajazleung/pen/BJgXYp

I have this transition-group which I expect to have fade effect when I click the 'CONSTRUCTION PROGRESS' tab, but no transition is seen.

```
<transition-group name="fade" class="row no-gutters" v-show="currentTab !== 'living'">
  <div class="col-6 pr-3 pb-3" v-for="(item, index) in constructionGallery" :key="'construction' + item">
    <img :src="item.photoThumbSmall" alt="Gallery Photo index" class="img-fluid">
    <p>fserf</p>
  </div>
</transition-group>
```

From what I see from the Chrome Inspector, no classes are added to the transitioned elements.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the entering/exiting `<transition-group>` is being added/removed immediately when the `v-show` evaluation changes. The two tab templates should be inside a single `<transition-group>`:

```
<transition-group name="fade" class="row no-gutters">
  <template v-if="currentTab === 'living'">...</template>
  <template v-else>...</template>
</transition-group>
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/ypmBXw?editors=1010)